# How to prepend existing alias in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, alias, zsh

I have existing alias for ls from oh-my-zsh suite.

```
igor@shogun ~ % alias ls
ls='ls -G'
igor@shogun ~ %
```

This alias depends on various settings like OS, color settings and so on. Therefore I can't just overwrite and would like prepend existing alias to something like this:

```
LC_COLLATE=C ls -G
```

But this does not work as expected, '-G' is gone:

```
igor@shogun ~ % alias ls='LC_COLLATE ls'
igor@shogun ~ % alias ls
ls='LC_COLLATE ls'
igor@shogun ~ %
```

I can do:

```
igor@shogun ~ % alias ls
ls='ls -G'
igor@shogun ~ % alias ls="LC_COLLATE=C `alias ls|sed -E "s/ls='(.*)'/\1/"`"
igor@shogun ~ % alias ls
ls='LC_COLLATE=C ls -G'
igor@shogun ~ %
```

Ugly! :)

Any elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No dependency to external program like sed.

```
eval old$(alias ls);alias ls="LC_COLLATE=C $oldls"
```